# Rails object does not return has_many subclass object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got below setup in my Ticket.rb model

```
has_many :note
```

And in note.rb model

```
belongs_to :ticket
```

But I cannot seem to get note id or description using below code:

```
  def show
    @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
    @note_id = @ticket.note.id
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render json: @ticket }
    end
  end
```

It doesn't seem to detect note class at all when I call `@ticket.node`

I also have note table populated with a row that has `ticket_id` aswell

What could be wrong?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Is `@note_id` coming out `nil`? Was the `note` belonging to `@ticket` actually created at some point?

Answer (score 0):

`Ticket.note` is a has **many**. It behaves like an array.

You either need to change it to `has_one :note`, or use `@ticket.note.first.id`. If you're not sure if the note exists for a given ticket, you could try `@ticket.note.first.try(:id)`.

Comment: Also, for readability, rename `Ticket.note` to `Ticket.notes`